# Spring Boot + Security + JWT can't generate token

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, jwt

I configured spring boot and security with JWT, everything worked wonders for a while.

this is my webSecurityConfig

```
httpSecurity
            .csrf().disable()
            .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedHandler).and()
            .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/user/cadastrar/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/auth/**").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated();
    httpSecurity
            .addFilterBefore(authenticationTokenFilterBean(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    httpSecurity.headers().cacheControl();
```

The first route "/users/cadastrar" works fine.

The problem is my second route "/auth"
Calling /auth with username and password on the body it will land on this function in my JwtAuthenticationTokenFilter class

```
protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws ServletException, IOException {
    String authToken = request.getHeader(this.tokenHeader);
    String username = jwtTokenUtil.getUsernameFromToken(authToken);
    logger.info("checking authentication for user " + username);
    if (username != null && SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() == null) {
        UserDetails userDetails = this.userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(username);
        if (jwtTokenUtil.validateToken(authToken, userDetails)) {
            UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails, null, userDetails.getAuthorities());
            authentication.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request));
            logger.info("authenticated user " + username + ", setting security context");
            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
        }
    }
    chain.doFilter(request, response);
}
```

Then it will go to my AuthenticationController class and run this function

```
@RequestMapping(value = "${jwt.route.authentication.path}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<?> createAuthenticationToken(@RequestBody JwtAuthenticationRequest authenticationRequest, Device device) throws AuthenticationException {

    // Perform the security
    final Authentication authentication = authenticationManager.authenticate(
            new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                    authenticationRequest.getUsername(),
                    authenticationRequest.getPassword()
            )
    );
    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);

    // Reload password post-security so we can generate token
    final UserDetails userDetails = userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(authenticationRequest.getUsername());
    final String token = jwtTokenUtil.generateToken(userDetails, device);

    // Return the token
    return ResponseEntity.ok(new JwtAuthenticationResponse(token));
}
```

the problem seems to be this specific part of the code:

```
// Perform the security
    final Authentication authentication = authenticationManager.authenticate(
            new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                    authenticationRequest.getUsername(),
                    authenticationRequest.getPassword()
            )
    );
```

When it tries to return the object "UserNamePasswordAuthenticationToken" it just sends the break point to the end of the function "doFilterInternal" specifically to the bracket after after the "chain.doFilter" call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is solved! Apparently coding for 16hours in a row affects how you think!

There is nothing wrong with the code above, for some reason I was setting my newly created users disabled by default!